# TABLE выходит за правую границу DIV

Tags: html, css

как поместит содержимое TABLE в DIV не выходя из границы DIV сейчас выглядеть так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

нужно сделать так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Добавьте в стили:

```
   table tr td.td2:last-child {
        word-break: break-word;
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо помогли.

Comment: Это решения не работает на opera и firefox почему то

Answer (score 1):

Решил задачу, оказывается у меня слипались слово в одно, в котором получил длинные абзацы, разделил их пробелом и получил то что хотел: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

CSS: Необходимо убрать фиксированную ширину блока

```
div { 
  width: auto;
}
```

Либо сделать фиксированную ширину блока, а у таблицы нет.

```
div { width: 300px; } table { width: 100%; }
```

Comment: мне именно под `width: 300px;` нужно смотрите вторую картинку, все вмешается под `width: 300px;`

Comment: `table { width: 100%; }` не помогает вы можете перейти по ссылке и сами убедится в этом.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lkcwm65w/
вот пример, либо я не понял проблему. Попробуйте поиграться со свойством position у блока

Comment: мне почему то не помогает такая фишка

Comment: Вы должны понять что здесь дело не в таблице, а в настроенных стилях других элементов. Попробуйте убрать .col-xs-12 убрать width: 100%, а у .desc сделать ширину меньше чем 800+. И не забывайте про позиционирование

Comment: тогда почему, когда я убираю `width: 300px` у div'а получаю `width 100%` от родителя а когда делаю `300px div table` уменьшается только до `546px`